# Cannot access the parent formControl object changes in a Parent-Child Component relationship in Angular 8

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-input

I have created a parent component as follows:

```
<form [formGroup] = "cardForm">
<app-inputvalidator [controls] = "cardForm.get('name')"></app-inputvalidator>  
</form>
```

Parent ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl,Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-card-form',
  templateUrl: './card-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card-form.component.css']
})

export class CardFormComponent implements OnInit {
  nameFormControl ;

   cardForm =  new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', [Validators.minLength(5),Validators.maxLength(25)])
  });



  constructor() {
   }

 ngOnInit(): void {
     this.nameFormControl = this.cardForm.get('name');
            }

}
```

I am passing the nameFormControls to the child component and accessing it in the template as well as class as follows:

InputValidator.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
 import { FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

 @Component({
  selector: 'app-inputvalidator',
  templateUrl: './inputvalidator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inputvalidator.component.css']
})
 export class InputvalidatorComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() controls: FormControl;

 constructor() {

 }

 ngOnInit(): void {
 }
```

}

Input Validator.html

```
  <input [formControlName] = "controls"  
  <br>
  <div>{{ controls.errors | json}}</div>
```

The project is compiled successfully with no errors.

I am getting the value of controls.errors to always null.
Why can I not print the object controls.errors using string interpolation as the value in the name input box changes?

Comment: Have you tried `@Input() controls: FormControl;` to `@Input() controls: AbstractControl;`. Also, call value change subscription of formControl on child component. and make console inside that value change and check it has error or not

Comment: Also use [formControl] instead of [formControlName]. If you are bind formcontrol without formgroup in html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> you get null becuase you don't put required validator the **min,maxLength** validators will return an error if there is value and the value is not valid , if the value is null or empty string this will consider a valid

check the validator  [source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9.1.0/packages/forms/src/validators.ts#L287)

Comment: Yes it works.
As in the parent component formControlName directive is used,
hence i used the same in child component.
Can yo please explain the working that happens under the hood.
That would be great.
Thanks for quick help.

Comment: @malbarmavi There is no use of `nameFormControl`. Can you please remove it from your example. So it's good if someone is new in formControl or in angular.

Comment: Yes the above provided solution works. Thanks malbarmavi and @Shashikant Devani

Comment: @PranavBhagwat happy to help 